# Python search 4 columns returning all nonzero values from the first column with a non zero value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
|ID|Top|Bottom|Duration|TotalInj|PerMeterInj|Opt1|Opt2|Opt3|RefP|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |0   |15  |0   |23  |
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |0   |0   |10  |23  |
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |24  |13  |0   |23  |
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |22  |0   |12  |23  |
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |25  |0   |0   |23  |
```

And it needs to loop through Opt1, Opt2, and Opt3 to find the first nonzero value and then return all nonzero values in that column, so in this example it would return the last 3 rows and only Opt1:

```
|ID|Top|Bottom|Duration|TotalInj|PerMeterInj|Opt1|
--------------------------------------------------
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |24  |
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |22  |
|1 |10 |5     |20      |23.8    |4.76       |25  |
```

If all values in Opt1 are zero, it searches the Opt2 column, etc. If all Opt1,2,3 are zero then it returns one row with the RefP (which is always constant).

Previously I created a dataframe with only the last 4 columns and used the ravel() function to find only the first non zero value, but now i need to return all nonzero values for the first column that has nonzero values.

Comment: Why first 2 rows are omited?

Comment: @jezrael because it needs to only return rows with non zero values

Comment: What will happen if first row opt1 value is non zero and second row value of opt1 is zero.? should df contain both the columns?

Comment: If the first and third rows contain non zero values then it would only return those rows. I was thinking a good approach would be to find which column has a nonzero value, then use .query() to filter the dataframe by > 0, but I can't work the logic out

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
def find_nonzeros():
    for i, col in enumerate(["Opt1", "Opt2", "Opt3"]):
        if df[col].nonzero(): #if there are any nonzero values
            return df.iloc[df[col].nonzero()[0], list(range(6)) + [6 + i]]
    return df.iloc[0, list(range(6)) + [len(df.columns)-1]]
```

Comment: Throws an error that the first return is outside a function

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `RefP` column. Now this snippet should do what you want

Comment: when I run it I get "KeyError: ('Opt1', 'Opt2', 'Opt3')" @colonder

Comment: I updated my answer. Are your columns named `Opt1`, `Opt2`, `Opt3`?. If they're not then you have to change them in this code snippet...

Comment: Yeah, they're named correctly and i replaced all the df's with the name of my dataframe and it's working now returning a blank dataframe so I think i can work with this from here.